# Rent a motorbike vs taking an organized ride/tour in Indonesia?

Tags: tours, rental, indonesia, motorcycles, tourist-traps

In Indonesia, there is often a not-advertised way of visiting places.

Whether it's about visiting a famous temple, go to a volcano, visit a few local craftsmen, and so on. It's often possible to simply rent a motorbike (scooter) and do it on your own.

Why would I choose to do it on my own rather than do it with a prearranged tour/ride?

---

#### Related questions:

[Probolinggo to Bromo by motorbike, possible?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/49599/9395)

[Yogyakarta to mount Merapi by scooter, possible?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/49603/9395)

[Banyuwangi to Kawa Ijen by motorbike, possible?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/49598/9395)

[Is it possible to motorcycle through Southeast Asia?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/30707/9395)

Comment: Asking 'why' makes this opinion based, maybe you can rewrite the question so it will be about facts.

Comment: @Willeke fair enough, edited

Answer (score 2):

The primary reason for doing it on your own is usually lower cost and more flexibility.

The primary reason of doing it with a guided tour is the local knowledge that your guide can share with you.

So a traveler needs to decide, do they want to save money and just go look at it, or do they want to come away with an insiders understanding of it.  And no, Lonely Planet is not a good substitute for a local guide's knowledge (my apologies Tony & Maureen).

Comment: One thing though, more often than not, you can find guides on site, so you can simply do the ride on your own and get a guide whenever you feel like it (at the temple/volcano/...). Unless the place you visit does not have any guide... Which may just mean you don't need one

Comment: I suppose I would value a guide, even for the part of the ride, if the guide is very good. Often I just feel the he's just in "driver mode", hence don't say much (if anything), which is fine, but has no value for me really.